# Comments in kotlin chained calls

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

Since when writing kotlin code, there often are longer call chains needing explanation. What would be the best place to add comments in this chain?

```
val map = javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/response.csv")
    .reader() //commentLocation1
    .readLines()
    .drop(1)
    // commentLocation2
    .map { it.split(",") }
    .map {
        // commentLocation3
        it.first().toInt() to it[2]
    }
    .toMap()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not found any hints about this in [the official coding conventions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html), but I would prefer commentLocation1 and commentLocation3. But remember that preferable way to express your intensions in code is adding function with good name. So if you feel that it's necessary to add comment for description the business value of some mapping, filtering and so on, it's better to use reference to function, which name explains it.

Comment: I already checked the official kotlin docs, and also couldn't find any examples on libraries like RxJava anywhere. I'll probably go with moving code to functions and using function references then!

Answer (score 3):

It's just a personal preference, but I don't like comments outside the docs, IMHO it reduces the chance to keep outdated comments on the code, so I recommend wrap the code into a function with any explanations that you find necessary:

```
/**
 * This function does something very useful =)
 */
fun function(){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I consider wanting to comment in the middle of a chain to be a sign you've made your chain too long. If you break it up, you can use the variable names to add quite a bit of "self-documentation."

```
val responseReader = javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/response.csv").reader()
val linesWithoutHeader = responseReader.readLines().drop(1)
val splitLines = linesWithoutHeader.map{it.split(","))}
val map = splitLines.map(firstAndThirdColumns).toMap()
def firstAndThirdColumns(...
```

This also has the advantage of giving you a more precise location for error messages, and allows you to insert type annotations to double-check something in the middle.  When someone is maintaining this later, they may be able to go off of an intermediary variable name instead of reconstructing the entire state in their head from the beginning of the chain. And worst case, if you still feel you need a comment, you can make it a regular line comment that doesn't look so awkward.